# How to get sub-Tensor from the SparseTensor using index?

Tags: python, tensorflow, indexing

I am trying to get the tensor from another big tensor by using index. The big tensor is too large and it can't be loaded into the memory, so I have to use the sparseTensor to store the big tensor. I have tried using the "tf.gather()" function, but it can't process sparseTensor. Can anyone give me some advices to solve this problem?